# how to put border image inside of div

Tags: html, css, border, border-image

When using `border-image` CSS property, the border is placed outside of `div`. Is there any way to put the border image inside of `div`?

```
border-width: 50px;
border-image: url(Border.png) 50 repeat;
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work for border-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/zxaLjY)

Is that what you mean?

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <span>

 </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-width: 50px;
  border-image: url(https://www.castlejackpot.com/wp-content/uploads/dynamik-gen/theme/images/home-horizontal-border.png) 50 repeat;
}
```